# How to find kurtosis and skewness by QQ plot?

Tags: probability, statistics

When a random QQ plot is given, how to tell the distribution kurtosis(larger than 3 or less than 3) and skewness (symmetric, negatively skewed or positively skewed), sometimes it might be intuitive, but how to describe it in mathematical terms.
Such those plots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Intuition may be the best you get - your first example looks left-skewed (extreme lower sample values but not upper sample values compared to normal) while your second looks as if it probably has negative excess kurtosis (lack of extreme upper or lower sample values compared to normal), but I would not want to guess the kurtosis of the first example

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfect mathematical connection between the q-q plot and the skewness and kurtosis statistics.  See here for an explanation as regards kurtosis:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354076/102879

A similar representation can be used for skewness.